# How rehearsed/scripted are the judges' responses on America's Got Talent?

Tags: americas-got-talent

Sometimes the responses of the *America's Got Talent* judges seem to be well rehearsed or, based on the questions they ask, at least the result of being given information about the contestants ahead of time.

And at other times, the judges seem to be unnaturally oblivious to reality.

The most extreme example of the latter is with respect to *Hans*.
Heidi Klum is still naïvely unaware that when she speaks to him in German, Hans doesn't understand a word of it.
And surely Simon Cowell, who's associated with "Australia's Got Talent", must know who this performer really is.

Yes, I know that (like professional wrestling) it's all entertainment, but it would be nice to know how much, if any, of the judges' behaviour is spontaneous.